# How to install 'Development Tools' into a CentOS machine without internet?

Tags: centos, yum

I need gcc, make and other essential stuff on a CentOS machine. The thing is that the machine is not (and probably will not be) connected to the internet.

Downloading the packages on some other computer, then moving and installing them here seems as an option. However, to compile packages I need *make* in the first place as far as I know.

What should I do? How can I get *make* here? How can I use *yum* to install packages from the local drive?

Comment: If you have the CentOS DVD, you can set up a local repository and just proceed with regular yum commands.

Answer (score 2):

Resolve your package dependencies from a same distro release version (major at least)
Download them all with yumdownloader from an internet connected box.
You might need to install yumdownloader first on the network box.
Transfer them rpm and profit!

Comment: Note: `yumdownloader` has a `--resolve` switch which will download all the dependencies, but that will be based on the state of the machine you run it on.

Comment: Install VirtualBox on Windows, reproduce your CentOS setup there and fiddle with it.

Comment: @trxrg probably trying to stop solving a social problem by technical means. There has to be somebody in charge. You can also install VirtualBox on another computer where you actually have admin rights and try to reproduce your CentOS setup there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have `make` before any installation. `rpm` operates on packages - so all stuff inside a package.rpm is already compiled (except *-devel.rpm etc.). Just do as you mentioned, download needed rpm's, copy to destination machine and do rpm -ihv yourstuff.rpm (and yes, remember about dependencies).